# Can I make a printable web page as same as its normal view with its all css features?

Tags: css, printing, html

I have a web application that produce some reports in HTML format. I have different styling options to display these forms. Normally whenever I want to print these pages, I lose all CSS styling features. How can I make a print without any change in appearance?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/css/print.css" type="text/css" media="screen, print" />
```

Comment: How are you attaching your CSS files?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/css/print.css" type="text/css" media="screen, print" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the print-out should use the same css-styling as the screen unless you specify something else.

Do you specify "media" in the css link?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

You could try to either make sure there is no media specified or to set media="screen, print"...

Comment: Yes I have css link in the code, and also tested media for it, but my problem is still alive.

Comment: Could printer settings affect the result? E.g. in IE there's an option to enable printing of background images and colors. 
Perhaps you could post some code that re-produces your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use some JavaScript plugin (like: jQuery-Print) you would lose your appearance in the other way if you use CSS correctly it's impossible to have a change in your print usually?! 
if your problem don't solve tell me which language do you use for your application?

Comment: There is no usage from something like jQuery in my print page.