# How to print web page with all its applied css?

Tags: css, printing

I want to print my table that contains some css styles too. But whenever I run `window.print()`, the output appears without any applied css to styling headers and footers.

I've used `<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="all" />` in my code. Also I tested it with `media="print"`. But still I have a print preview without any style.

What should I do?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698826/print-web-page-as-same-as-its-view

Comment: I did not get appropriate answer from it, and it is not visible in the top questions to view. So I had to ask it again.

Answer (score -1):

media=print should do.

Make sure you have also checked the "print images and colors" in page setup while seeing the Print Preview.

Comment: The question clearly says that they tried `media="print"`, but it didn't work.